# CentOS 7 Can ping but cannot browse

Tags: linux, centos

I have install CentOS 7, I unable to update  unless I add the mirror list into my `/etc/hosts`.

I can ping to what ever domain but cannot browse unless I put the address in my hosts file.

The ping command successful:

```
$ ping yahoo.com
PING yahoo.com (98.138.253.109) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ir1.fp.vip.ne1.yahoo.com (98.138.253.109): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=242 ms
64 bytes from ir1.fp.vip.ne1.yahoo.com (98.138.253.109): icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=242 ms
64 bytes from ir1.fp.vip.ne1.yahoo.com (98.138.253.109): icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=241 ms
^C
--- yahoo.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 241.374/241.939/242.420/0.713 ms
```

The curl command fails:

```
$ curl yahoo.com
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: yahoo.com; Unknown error
```

Comment: What result you get by running the command nslookup yahoo.com

Comment: nslookup yahoo.com
    Server:  8.8.8.8
    Address: 8.8.8.8#53

    Non-authoritative answer:
    Name: yahoo.com
    Address: 98.139.183.24
    Name: yahoo.com
    Address: 206.190.36.45
    Name: yahoo.com
    Address: 98.138.253.109

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop firewalld `service firewalld stop`
2. Start iptables `service iptables start`
3. Add these rules: `iptables -I INPUT -j ACCEPT`, and `iptables -I OUTPUT -j ACCEPT`
4. If this works, save the commands with: `service iptables save`